# reactjs find x value from object

Tags: reactjs

I have just started with react.js and I got a little bit confused with object, accessing, getting values and all that.

I have an object that goes like this:

```
Array(5) [ 
0: Object {id:"1",name:"Jack"}
1: Object {id:"2",name:"John"}
2: Object {id:"3",name:"Ben"}
]
```

Now what I want to is access the second name("John" with it's ID).
I already have its ID taken from an text input but I am not sure how can I get the object values in a loop and then compare the names with X name for example.
Can you please help me figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

try below code:

```
const result = yourArray.find(item => item.id === YOUR_INPUT_VALUE)
```

Comment: It returns `undefined`. Should this work with the structure of my object too? I guess I'm missing something.

Comment: Could you complete your question with your input value?

Comment: If it returned undefined it mean that there is nothing to match with your input value

Answer (score 0):

```
const myArray = [
{id:"1",name:"Jack"},
{id:"2",name:"John"},
{id:"3",name:"Ben"},]
```

then

```
console.log(myArray[1].id)
```

result

```
console.log(myArray[1].name)
```

result

```
Jack
```

Comment: Well, this works but it's supposed to be dynamically. I can't always know at what index is "jack" placed. It can be other than [1]. I have to make it search inside of the array.

Comment: const myObject = [
    { id: 1, name: "Jack" },
    { id: 2, name: "John" },
    { id: 3, name: "Ben" }
  ];
  const findByID = (id) => {
    const result = myObject.find((item) => item.id === id);
    console.log(result.name);
  };
  console.log(findByID(2));